# How to initialize a generic variable

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble working with generics. I have a class as

```
public class findMinMax<T extends Comparable <T>> {
  
   private T min; 
   private T max;
   
   public findMinMax() {
     //Need to initialize min max to something so that I can compare them
   }
    
   public void find(T value) {
      if (min == null || min.compareTo(value) > 0) 
         min = value;
      if (max == null ||value.compareTo(max) > 0)
         max = value;
   }
}
```

So how can you initialize a generic variable? Thanks

Comment: The minimum and maximum value will be different for different types. One way is you can take it as a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Why did you remove the code from your question?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit the code but ended up not saving it

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize them to `null` (actually they will be `null` by default, so no need to explicitly initialize them), but then you'll need to add `null` checks in your `find` method:

```
public class findMinMax<T extends Comparable <T>> {
  
   private T min; 
   private T max;
   
   public findMinMax() {
   }
    
   public void find(T value) {
      if (min == null || min.compareTo(value) > 0) 
         min = value;
      if (max == null || value.compareTo(max) > 0)
         max = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic information is only used at compile time. The 'T' and its meaning has disappeared in compiled (and running) code.

But you can pass the class by constructor, and create an instance in a generic way:

```
public class findMinMax<T extends Comparable <T>> {

   private T value;
   private T min;
   private T max;

   public findMinMax(Class<T> aClass)
   {
       value = aClass.newInstance();
       min = aClass.newInstance();
       max = aClass.newInstance();
   }

   ....
}
```

The concrete class T needs a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable is `null`-friendly. But your code is not.

If you want to make your code `null`-friendly, use this:

```
public class FindMinMax<T extends Comparable <T>> {
  
   private T min; 
   private T max;
   private boolean firstCall = true;
   
   public void find(T value) {
      if (firstCall) {
        min = value;
        max = value;
        firstCall = false;
      } else if (value != null) {
        if (value.compareTo(min) < 0) {
          min = value;
        }
        if (value.compareTo(max) > 0) {
          max = value;
        }
      } else {
        if (min != null && min.compareTo(value) > 0) {
          min = value;
        }
        if (max != null && max.compareTo(value) < 0) {
          max = value;
        }
      }
   }
}
```